# PyAudio Input Overflowed -9981 - No solution working

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

**Please do not report this question as a duplicate, because none of the already available Solution working for me, I tested them all**

So,
I am trying to run a PyAudio sample Recording program in my RaspberryPi model B board,
This is the error I am getting,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pyaudio/test/testing.py", line 23, in <module>
    data = stream.read(chunk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 605, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames)
IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981
```

There are certain solutions already available that solved many user's problem, which in my case, isn't true.

Here is what I've tried,

First of all, Here is the code,

```
"""PyAudio example: Record a few seconds of audio and save to a WAVE file."""

import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
   data = stream.read(CHUNK)
   frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

I have also tried if the current configuration is supported or not,

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
if p.is_format_supported(48000.0, 
    input_device=1,
    input_channels=1,
    input_format=pyaudio.paInt16):
    print 'True!'
```

Both 44,000 and 44,100 are support but still I'm getting the same error again and again.

This is my USB Audio Card device info,

```
p.get_device_info_by_index(1)

{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 
'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.011609977324263039, 
'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.011609977324263039, 
'maxInputChannels': 1L, 
'structVersion': 2L, 
'hostApi': 0L, 
'index': 1, 
'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.046439909297052155, 
'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 
'name': u'Generic USB Audio Device: USB Audio (hw:1,0)', 
'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.046439909297052155}
```

Does anybody has any idea as why I'm still getting the error ?

Comment: Can you post what happens if you do `p.get_default_input_device_info()`?

Comment: @joseph I am also facing the same problem and same error,
the information I get from the command `p.get_default_input_device_info()`  is 
`{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.011609977324263039, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.011609977324263039, 'maxInputChannels': 1L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 0L, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.046439909297052155, 'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 'name': u'USB PnP Sound Device: USB Audio (hw:0,0)', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.046439909297052155}`

guide me to resolve this issue?

Comment: @FahadUddin, try lowering or increasing your chunk size

Comment: @SufiyanGhori I tried 1024, 512, 256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try setting exception_on_overflow to False?  From the Pyaudio documentation:

```
read(num_frames, exception_on_overflow=True)
```

Read samples from the stream. Do not call when using non-blocking mode.

Parameters: 
num_frames – The number of frames to read.
exception_on_overflow – Specifies whether an IOError exception should be thrown (or silently ignored) on input buffer overflow. Defaults to True.
Raises IOError: 
if stream is not an input stream or if the read operation was unsuccessful.
Return type:
string

Comment: This does not appear to work with PyAudio 0.2.8. (which is what ships with the Pi as of Feb 17) I get "Unexpected Keyword" If I just try to add `False` (no keyword, just the argument), I get told that there are too many arguments.

Comment: @Sidd You saved my day! Thanks you!

Answer (score 5):

Change your chunk parameter to 8192 instead of 1024. Worked for me.
reference: [IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174540/ioerror-errno-input-overflowed-9981)

Answer (score 0):

```
# importing modules for sound handling
# importing modules for sound handling
from sys import byteorder
from array import array
from struct import pack

import pyaudio
import wave

def audioeffect():
    CHUNK = 16 # played with, this can be 2048 1024, 512, 256 etc
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 48000

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
    r = array('h') # define r
    snd_data = array('h', stream.read(CHUNK)) # read sounddata from input
    r.extend(snd_data)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    N = 1
    SumOfSquars = 0
    for i in snd_data:  # determing the value for tel of  
        N = N +1

    # adding all quadrates
    for i in range(0, N-1):
        SumOfSquars = snd_data[i]**2
    Rms_Value = np.sqrt(SumOfSquars / N)

    #print("Rms_Value is  :", Rms_Value)
    return int(Rms_Value)
```

Comment: First i used rate 44100 and was bombarded by errors and overflow etc. with RATE = 48000, it works. CHUNK is 16 in my case because i only want a very short sample to drive a APA Led String.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Can you explain what this does? Remember that answers are for a wider audience than just the original asker. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just increased the chunk number and it appears that it works!
here's my code

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 44100  #just a big number
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1 #i found that my mic has 1 channel
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input_device_index=3, #found that also
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

elaborating on @Sidd Rajput 's answer since I did not find this clearly stated,
it's not enough to set this inside your script/project, if you're importing  -- pyaudio.py itself needs to be modified

```
def read(self, num_frames, exception_on_overflow=False):
```

^Line 589/590 in pyaudio.py v0.2.8: